# How can I convert the non url friendly characters to URL friendly characters in address bar?

Tags: php, url

How can I convert the non-url friendly chracters in address bar to show it as url-friendly slug.

For example I want the string `http://www.example.com/?q=test%20words%20string` to be displayed as `http://www.example.com/?q=test words string` or `http://www.example.com/?q=test-words-string`.

P.S.: I am passing the value using GET method in form.

Comment: I need to change it in browser address bar Can it be done by.htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replce string. Replace the `space` with `-`

```
<?php $your_string = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($your_string)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.urldecode.php) function:

```
$str = urldecode($url);
```

You may then convert the string `$str` any way you wish, for example use a sluggifier, which is probably the best option for all cases. It takes a lot of things into account you probably won't be able to do yourself. This is an [example of a sluggifier](https://gist.github.com/elieandraos/5813220).

If you use Symfony you have the sluggifier as a plug-in, so it also depends on what framework you are using, if you use one at all.

Comment: I need to change it in browser address bar Can it be done by.htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first decode the url

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/?q=test%20words%20string";
$nUrl = urldecode($url) //outputs http://www.example.com/?q=test words string
```

now

```
$fUrl = str_replace(' ','-',$nUrl);
```

Comment: I need to change it in browser address bar Can it be done by.htaccess?